# IMC controller - What reference model should I use?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I'm going to build an IMC controller, Internal Model Control.

[image]

The Forward Model is the reference model. If the Plant and the Forward Model is identical, it will result a zero value to the Feedback Signal. But in reality, the reference model is not identical as the plant model.

So my simple question is: How should I design the Forward Model?

1. A approximation model of the real system by using standard transfer functions templates? Example: First order, Second order etc.
2. A transfer function as Forward Model which has been created by using advanced system identification?

Can I interpret an IMC controller as a disturbance compensator?

Comment: probably better ask https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Memming why? It's a control question. Pure math.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson: It is not pure math, but I agree that it is applied math. Normally the forward model should represent the time-dependent trajectory that you want to follow. The controller/compensator is there to attenuate the deviation from the desired trajectory. As far as I remember the forward model should be linked to the reference input, or this is some other type of control architecture.

Comment: @MrYouMath I take that as "The Forward model should be as close as possible equal to the real plant". Right?